# Is there an incestuous relationship in Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In Avengers: age of Ultron, I got the sense that the relationship between Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch may have incestuous undertones. They are often unusually close, holding hands, or sharing seemingly suggestive glances.

Is there any info to support this?

Comment: This was likely to indicate their closeness as siblings, rather than as lovers. With limited screen time, trying to convey such a relationship may be difficult, especially since these characters did not have the lions share of the screen time

Comment: Protip: Don't watch Age of Ultron right after a Game of Thrones marathon. ;-)

Comment: Not sure why all the down votes. In "Ultimate Avengers," the incestuous nature of the twins relationship is quite explicitly stated.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Probably because it's a question that leads with an assumption that all intimate behavior is sexual.

Answer (score 12):

I think you're reading too much into it. It's not uncommon for siblings, even adult ones, to hold hands, especially in times of stress. Add to this that this particular pair had endured some pretty traumatic events, including the loss of parents, and its easy to see that they might be a bit closer still than your typical siblings.

As for exchanging glances, I don't think they carry any meaning other than a form of unspoken communication.  Remember, these two have been orphaned for much of their lives, so its natural that they lean on each other for support.

Edit:

Forgot to add the point that not only are these two siblings, they are *twins*, which adds a whole other layer to the point about unspoken communication.

Answer (score 0):

In the Ultimates Universe from the comics they were a couple so it is very likely that there was intentional subtext (I mean, those two actors had been in a movie together before as a married couple), but it wouldn’t go much beyond subtext. There is no way Disney would let that be completely canonical in their universe.